# In $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, the sup norm and the $L^1$ norm are not equivalent.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

How does the proof here show that the two norms are not equivalent? We have that in the sup norm $f_n$ converges to $1$, and in the $L^1$ norm $f_n$ converges to $0$, but how does this mean that the two norms are not equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two norms were equivalent then the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-neighborhood $U_{1/2}(0)$  would have to contain a  $\|\cdot\|_1$-neighborhood  $V_\epsilon(0)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. But your example shows that any such $V_\epsilon(0)$ contains functions $f_n$ lying outside of $U_{1/2}(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Because this means that in the $L_1$ norm, any open neighbourhood of the function $f(x)=0$ contains infinitely many $f_n$, while for the sup norm, for instance the open ball of radius $\frac12$ around $f$ contains none of the $f_n$.